# How to create a table using multiple span in one div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I got the following problem.

I am trying to create 2 columns using `span` with multiple rows inside a `div`.
I am able to get the 2 columns but not not multiple rows.

The HTML code can't be changed.

```css
span{
  display: inline-block;
}
.totalAmount-dd:after, .oldTotal-dd:after, .totalDue-dd:after  {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
.totalAmount, .oldTotal, .totalDue{
  float: left;
}
.totalAmount-dd, .oldTotal-dd, .totalDue-dd{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="payment-breakdown">
  <span class="totalAmount">Total:</span>
  <span class="totalAmount-dd">100USD</span>
  <span class="oldTotal">Previously paid:</span>
  <span class="oldTotal-dd">50USD</span>
  <span class="totalDue">Amount Due:</span>
  <span class="totalDue-dd">50USD</span>
</div>
```

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Why aren't you using a table ?

Comment: Agreed...this is clearly a place for an actual table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the whole css of your own and solve it using this simple css snippet:

```
.payment-breakdown span{
  display: block;
  width: 50%; 
  float: left;
}
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/fwrx2whv/)</kbd>

You can style each column using the pseudo selectors `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)`.

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE DEMO WITH STYLED COLUMNS**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/fwrx2whv/2/)</kbd>

Comment: It work great. I understand the display and the float. But how come by doing width 50%, the right column is created?

Comment: Hey @laurent, thats kind of a "big" question. I recommend to read this article: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ - as all elements want to float to the left, and they could use 100% of the parents div, using only the half size (50%) lets two span elements use the same row.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `float: left;` on all elements and give them a width of 50 percent. And use a clearfix to not get your page messed up afterwards.

```css
span{
  display: inline-block;
}
.totalAmount-dd:after, .oldTotal-dd:after, .totalDue-dd:after  {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
.totalAmount, .oldTotal, .totalDue, .totalAmount-dd, .oldTotal-dd, .totalDue-dd {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="payment-breakdown">
  <span class="totalAmount">Total:</span>
  <span class="totalAmount-dd">100USD</span>
  <span class="oldTotal">Previously paid:</span>
  <span class="oldTotal-dd">50USD</span>
  <span class="totalDue">Amount Due:</span>
  <span class="totalDue-dd">50USD</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.payment-breakdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
span {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.totalAmount,
.oldTotal,
.totalDue {
  text-align: left;
}
.totalAmount::after,
.oldTotal::after,
.totalDue::after {
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
}
.totalAmount-dd,
.oldTotal-dd,
.totalDue-dd {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="payment-breakdown">
  <span class="totalAmount">Total:</span>
  <span class="totalAmount-dd">100USD</span>
  <span class="oldTotal">Previously paid:</span>
  <span class="oldTotal-dd">50USD</span>
  <span class="totalDue">Amount Due:</span>
  <span class="totalDue-dd">50USD</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will find out more about flex box.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some javascript to add a br tag after every element.

```js
'use strict';
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].outerHTML += "<br/>";
}
```

```css
span{
  display: inline-block;
}
.totalAmount-dd:after, .oldTotal-dd:after, .totalDue-dd:after  {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
.totalAmount, .oldTotal, .totalDue{
  float: left;
}
.totalAmount-dd, .oldTotal-dd, .totalDue-dd{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="payment-breakdown">
  <span class="totalAmount">Total:</span>
  <span class="totalAmount-dd">100USD</span>
  <span class="oldTotal">Previously paid:</span>
  <span class="oldTotal-dd">50USD</span>
  <span class="totalDue">Amount Due:</span>
  <span class="totalDue-dd">50USD</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that you can't change the html as it seems a little peculiar to build the table from spans!

I think you'll want to clear your floats because of a height-issue associated with floats. Use something like [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) or [this.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Try that and then let me know if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code spinet

```
.payment-breakdown {
    overflow: auto;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.payment-breakdown span {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      display: table-cell;
      width: 25%;
  }
```